# PROPERTY LIST - Is it possible to Customize appearance in back office

Tags: episerver, episerver-7, episerver-8

I'm using a property list in the back office.

I have an image as one of the properties, the problem I have is it only shows the content Id in the property list table, this is a really poor UI experince.
In addition one of the properties are a URL, again instead of showing a friendly URL it shows and internal URL, again not a very good UI experince for a content editor.

Is there a way to change this?

[image]

I am new to EPI server and though I have come accross some good features, what is kind of disapoiting are elements of the UI, a property list table like this could look much much better than this.

Can I customise it?

Comment: The `PropertyList` editor is still beta stamped I think. You can create your own Dojo widget inheriting the default one to improve it, though.

Comment: Dojo widget - Not sure what that is, this is my first episerver project, but I will look it up - thanks